# How to pass the value to servlet in the following code segment?

Tags: jsp, servlets

```
   <form action="PetTransactionAction" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Pet Name</th>
       <th>Quantity Available</th>
       <th>Place</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th>Pet Type</th>
       </tr>
       <c:forEach items="${petsearch}" var="nm">
       <tr>  
         <td>${nm.id}</td>
         <td>${nm.pet_name}</td>
         <td>${nm.avl_qty}</td>
         <td>${nm.place}</td>
         <td>${nm.pet_age}</td>
         <td>${nm.pet_type}</td>
         <td><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="${nm.id}"></td>
         <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy"></td>
         </tr>
       </c:forEach>
       </table>
       </form>
```

How to get the specific value from hidden field in the servlet after submitting the form. I am using request.getParameter("hidden"); in servlet but it is giving only id of first record, how do i get the value of 3rd or 4th or any other record?

Answer (score 0):

use `String[] values=request.getParameterValues("hidden");` which will return an array of all parameters with name "hidden".

Since you need the hidden param of the row which you clicked you should have multiple forms

```
  <table>
    <tr>
   <th>#</th>
   <th>Pet Name</th>
   <th>Quantity Available</th>
   <th>Place</th>
   <th>Age</th>
   <th>Pet Type</th>
   </tr>
   <c:forEach items="${petsearch}" var="nm">
   <tr>  
     <td>${nm.id}</td>
     <td>${nm.pet_name}</td>
     <td>${nm.avl_qty}</td>
     <td>${nm.place}</td>
     <td>${nm.pet_age}</td>
     <td>${nm.pet_type}</td>

     <td colspan='2'>
      <form action="PetTransactionAction" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="${nm.id}">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy">
      </form>
     </td>
     </tr>
   </c:forEach>
   </table>
```

Comment: how do i get the value of id corresponding to the button i clicked?

Comment: it is impossible as there is only one form may be you can have multiple forms, see the edit

Comment: please suggest any solution to this, because i have to get the id corresponding to the button i click??

Answer (score 0):

In your Servlet, you could do use [getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) api on request something like:

```
String id = httpServletRequest.getParameter("hidden");//hidden is the name of your hidden field i.e. name="hidden"
```

This method will return the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist